# Kill subprocess in python using pid

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pid

I am using subprocess in python to start a program.When it starts it saves the pid of the process created in a database.After some time and if a trigger happens it needs to stop this process and start a new one.
The problem is that when I use subprocess.Popen().pid it returns the pid of a zombie process (defunct) and not the real process I need to stop.I cannot use the terminate command since the start process command and the kill command happens in different scripts.So I need a way to get the real pid of the process I am starting and not the pid of the zombie process.

Answer (score 0):

A zombie process is a dead process, which its data is still kept by the os to be returned to the calling process (exit value etc). You can't kill a zombie process, since it's already dead. There are 2 ways to get rid of it; either `Popen.wait()` for the subprocess from its parent before the parent exits or in the background using `Popen.poll()` if the parent process should keep running, OR kill all parent processes until the zombie's parent is `1 init`, and init will reap it automatically. You should then update your DB that your process exited, since linux may give the same pid to a new unrelated process (you may end up killing a process you didn't intend to kill).

If all you need is to stop the process, then don't worry - it is already stopped. However, you do need to worry about too many zombies in the system (some say that even 1 is too many), since linux will issue a pid for each process, and having too many of these may prevent you from being able to run new processes.

There's a hack to force parent processes to reap their children [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669597/killing-zombie-process-knowing-pid-in-linux-c).

Comment: I just want to get the correct pid of the process and not the pid of the zombie.I dont think I can accept this answer.Thank you anyway.

Comment: You have the correct pid. There is no other pid. The process has started with a pid, and exited. The pid does not change. You got the correct pid, but there's nothing you can do to reap it except the above.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.google.co.il/#q=what+is+a+zombie+process) will help.